# apache-nifi: how to pass the timezone into the crontab string

Tags: quartz-scheduler, apache-nifi

NIFI is able to schedule task using a crontab like strategy. Into some processor the scheduling tab you can select "CRON driven".

This CRON uses the [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) module, I found how to set the timezone into the scheduling using the code:

```
CronTrigger trigger = newTrigger()
  .withIdentity("name", "group")
  .withSchedule(
    cronSchedule("0 0 22 ? * *")
    .inTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Pacific/Honolulu"))
  )
  .startAt(calTZStarts.getTime())
  .endAt(calTZEnds.getTime())
  .build();
```

How Can I add the timezone into the Run Schedule text box shown in NIFI ?

```
* * * * * ?
```

Currently I see that NIFI is running the task in the timezone of my browser.

Answer (score 3):

Currently I don't think there is a way to do this from the Run Schedule text box. It looks like the Quartz code will use the JVM's default timezone when one has not been set on the cron expression.

You could try setting
 `-Duser.timezone=Pacific/Honolulu` 
in bootstrap.conf to make the timezone of your NiFi JVM be set to what you want, and then Quartz might pick that up.

Comment: Using your setting nifi shows into the workbench the the current TIME in UTC. This is a good start point however the crontabs are not affected by this setting.

Comment: As I also think it is a useful functionality I created a Ticket for it in the Nifi Issue Tracker: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-5532

Feel free to vote for it

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could schedule the process continuously and use RouteOnAttribute to do some calculations based on the Timezone to handle it properly with the following [expression language](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#format):

Create a boolean if now is greater then 10:30 in Pacific/Honolulu,
Can be used to route on that attribute. In the call to the second `format` function the time to compare can be set:

```
${now():format("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "Pacific/Honolulu"):toDate("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"):toNumber():gt(${now():format("yyyy/MM/dd 10:30:00.000'Z'", "Pacific/Honolulu"):toDate("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"):toNumber()})}
```

Further explanation of the commands used above:

String: Now in Pacific/Honolulu

```
${now():format("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "Pacific/Honolulu")}
```

Date: Now in Pacific/Honolulu

```
${now():format("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "Pacific/Honolulu"):toDate("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")}
```

Number: Now in Pacific/Honolulu

```
${now():format("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "Pacific/Honolulu"):toDate("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"):toNumber()}
```